# How do I work with a forked branch in xCode?

Tags: xcode, github, git-fork

I have forked a repository on GitHub, and cloned the repo to my machine. When I look at the source control navigator on xCode, I see the following:

[image]

When I click on each 'GitHub' and 'GroupUp' to see the repos on GitHub, I see that 'GitHub' is the original repo which I forked from, and 'GroupUp' is the forked repo. My question is: why does it seem as though I am currently checked out of two master's simultaneously? I would assume I can only ever be working on one branch at a time, but here it says (current) for both main branches. Also, what dictates the name of each repo on my machine i.e. why is one repo named 'GitHub' and another named 'GroupUp'? I didn't put this in myself.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`master` is just the name of a commit. If the current `master` commit of both repos is the same (because they are in sync), and that is also the commit that is your HEAD, they are both “current”.